Having problem with right hand's position on classical guitar
I am a self-taught classical guitar player and recently, a more experienced player pointed out that my right hand position is incorrect as my wrist is bent down a lot. To solve this problem, I searched and found this site:

Fingerpicking Hand Position

The fingers are almost perpendicular to the strings, pointing down toward the floor and cupped as if holding a ball.

The thumb is out and away from the fingers.

The wrist is slightly arched, with a space between the wrist and the guitar.

The hand is bent down slightly at the wrist.




However, I still can't resolve the issue since if I want my fingers to be perpendicular to the strings I should bent down my wrist a lot and if I hold my hand similar to the left image, I touch the strings with corner of the my fingertips and it is not perpendicular to the string.

@JohnBelzaguy - unsure what's 'right or wrong', but I find that when the inner arm is away from the belly of the guitar, the picking hand tends to float, or wander, making accurate picking more difficult.

Couple of things: firstly, it would really help those of us that play and teach classical guitar to see a picture of YOUR right-hand position while playing; secondly, the pictures you have in your post relate to finger-picking on steel-string acoustic, which is usually a little different to playing classical.

Neither photo shows my technique. You should be able to have the stroke come from the big knuckle only. I can’t do that without my wrist bent a bit. By that I mean my wrist is farther from the guitar than my hand or forearm. Maybe I’ll post an answer with a picture. Also check out The Art of Classical Guitar Playing by Charles Duncan. Used and recommended by gigging pros and college professors. Essential for self learner.

One more comment, the right hand image is nothing like accepted classical guitar technique. I strongly recommend against doing that.

Also regarding "pick style position" from the same web site, it says this: "The fingers not holding the pick are held out. The pinky can lightly touch the face of the guitar." I highly recommend against this as it puts unnecessary tension and restriction on the right hand. In summary, I would not use the linked site as a reference for any technique.

First off, while we would ideally all have full-length mirrors in our practice spaces, technique photos taken from the front of the guitar alone are just not so helpful.
Once again I'm going to recommend The Art of Classical Guitar Playing by Charles Duncan (Amazon link). It has photos and diagrams from the player's point of view, which is much more helpful. It is available in paperback and Kindle formats. There is an entire chapter on right-hand position.
Here are two excerpts:


And here's a photo of my technique. My wrist is more bent, maybe too bent, but I'm comfortable and haven't been criticized on this by teachers. We all have to adjust positioning and technique details to suit our particular body shapes (which Duncan also discusses):

One more important point about right hand position is that the forearm where the flexor muscles are largest should be approximately on the top corner of the lower bout of the guitar. This should be comfortable and rested but also able to apply slight pressure to the top of the guitar to counteract the fretting pressure applied to the fingerboard by the left hand. It is important to be conscious of this pressure and balance as part of right hand technique because the counter-force for the left hand fretting should not be the left hand thumb. The left hand thumb should only gently touch the back of the neck to provide stability and kinesthetic position sensing for the left hand fingers. The thumb muscles that provide "pinching" action should not be engaged in the left hand while playing classical guitar. Keep this fact in mind while refining your right hand and forearm positioning.

Thanks for the answer! I'm learning from a well-known guitarist named Babak Amini on YouTube. I'm curious if he uses the same position you have mentioned. Here is a video of him playing. I think it's somewhat similar, at least from my perspective.

@Soheil That YouTube channel has no classical guitar on it. It's a different style, not classical. If you want to learn that style, then your question should not have the word "classical" in it. I'm not sure what style that YouTube channel is - perhaps flamenco style?

Yes that is flamenco. Sorry for confusion I meant classical guitar in my post.

@Soheil Are you trying to learn classical or flamenco guitar? If you're trying to learn flamenco, you should ignore my answer. If you're trying to learn classical, you should ignore that YouTube channel.

Oh I'm new to guitar actually I have a classical guitar and want to practice flamenco techniques on it.

@Soheil Then my answer is wrong. I don't know flamenco style so I can't change my answer to how to play flamenco. Also you should change your question so that it says "flamenco" instead of "classical".

No your answer is helpful it was my misunderstanding during writing the question and didn't know that the different styles have different hand positions. Thanks for the help sure I will search more.

@Soheil You should ignore my answer if you are playing in the flamenco style because if you use my recommendations for flamenco style you might cause yourself injury. The hand position I recommend is only correct if you also position the guitar in the classical style with it resting on your left leg (not right leg) and with an elevated neck as shown in user1079505's answer. The hand position I've shown is not safe to use if your guitar is not positioned correctly in the classical style.

Putting my tuppence worth in here. First and foremost, you need a position that is comfortable to play in.
The thumb generally copes with the lower two/three strings, whilst i, m and a look after strings 3, 2 and 1. Not exclusively, but it's a start point.
When you rest your inner, lower arm on the belly of the guitar, it gives stability. I used to find that when students kept that part of the arm away, the hand would wallow and float around, making it more difficult to pluck the appropriate string with whichever digit.
In order to pluck with the fingertip or nail, yes, the hand needs to be shaped as if lightly holding a tennis ball. So, in order for that to happen, the wrist needs to be raised off the guitar's body. Giving the knuckles closest to the palm stability. As long as each digit is able to move independently (o.k. pinky hardly does!), with those knuckles hardly moving, everything should be playable. But if that's uncomfortable, there's some room for manoeuvre, but it's a good beginning position.
Of course, all this depends on the position of the guitar itself. The classic classical position works best, rather than slinging it like you might an electric!

Since you wrote you are self-taught, I suspect you might be holding the guitar in a way that the neck of the instrument is kind of parallel to the floor. Classical guitarists use footrests or supports (sometimes both) which lift the neck by a considerable angle. See e.g. this photo of Johanna Beisteiner (source: Wikipedia):

The plucking hand forearm is rested on the edge of the body of the instrument, and the hand is lifted naturally over the strings.
This position lets you pluck the strings at various distances from the bridge, and also vary the plucking angle. Both these factors impact the timbre of the instrument, and can be used for phrasing and articulation. This implies also there is no single "correct" angle of the hand.
Wikipedia happens to have a photo of the same guitarist holding the instrument in a more casual manner:

Please note how the plucking hand position changes. I'm fairly certain she could play reasonably well in this position, but maybe with less flexibility.
I encourage you to at least try to play in a classical position. The position of both hands stems from the position of your whole body and the instrument, not the other way round.

Note that in the top pic., she rests the guitar on her leg, but in the lower one, it's resting on a workbench,

@Tim yes, of course, but I don't think it changes the point I'm making.
